# Loop won't remove every instance of a character from a string

Tags: java

I am working on a project for class and we are required to only use charAt(), length(), substring(), and equals() to manipulate strings.

I am stuck on the bit that is removing every instance of a character from a string. If the string has consecutive identical characters the program leaves one everytime. Example is "afternoon". If I want to remove 'n' the program correctly removes n and the output is "afteroo." However, if I want to remove 'o' the output is "afternon."

This is what I have for this part of the program:

```
System.out.println("Enter the character to remove.");
removeChar = keyboard.nextLine();

char remove = removeChar.charAt(0),
     original;  

for(i=0; i < input.length(); i++){
    original = sentence.charAt(i);
    if(original == remove)
        sentence = sentence.substring(0,i) + sentence.substring(i+1);
}
System.out.println(sentence);
```

Comment: so you basically if you have "afternoon" and you want to remove "o" it should be "afternn" ?

Comment: You're using `i` to loop over `input`, but also manipulating `sentence` with it. Once you remove a character from `sentence`, `i` is no longer  valid way to splice `sentence`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are removing characters from the string in the for-loop, if you have two of the character to remove right in a row, the second one will get missed. This is due to the fact that when you remove the first one, the second one will move in index to where the first one was, then you will increment `i`. To fix this, either don't increment `i` when you remove a character, or store the indices of the characters you want to remove, and remove them all at once, from the back of the string to the front to avoid this same issue again. If you want to avoid incrementing `i` when you remove a character, a while loop would work better.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the suggestion of `UnknowableIneffible` or you can update `i` as follows:

```
if(original == remove){
    sentence = sentence.substring(0,i) + sentence.substring(i+1);
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UnknowableIneffible's answers makes a good point, a while loop would be easier in this case. You could also stick to your for loop, but go through it backwards:

```
for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

This way, you are not affected by the shifting characters, as it happens only "behind" you.

This works nicely when using for indexed loops to remove things from collections, too. Advanced loops throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, counting up leads will miss elements and causes `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but counting down does the trick.